# Java ImageIO.write() takes up to 6 seconds

Tags: java, servlets, javax.imageio

I am writing an web application where I need to send an image from servlet to client. Image is generated dynamically and is quite big(+-2MB). It might be jpeg, png, or gif.

Now, I am using ImageIO.write() to write the image to output stream, but its veeeery slow. It takes up to 6 seconds till the client see the image. I need to speed it up.

Any suggestions?

btw. I am aware of [Looking for a faster alternative to ImageIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293556/looking-for-a-faster-alternative-to-imageio) topic. But it didn't help me.
Since it's slow with PNG ImageMagick is not a solution and
I have tested JAI and it was even worse.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

To show you some code:

```
BufferedImage bi = [code to generate Image];
response.setContentType(mime);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bi,"png",out);
```

I stripped down Exception handling for readability.

Comment: Could network speed be the culprit here?

Comment: What happens if you write the image to a ByteArrayOutputStream? Is it fast or as slow? If it's fast, then you just have a bandwidth problem between the client and the server.

Comment: Are you using BufferedOutputStream, or some other form of buffering? Otherwise it's possible you're sending a lot of small packets.

Comment: Network speed is not the issue. Writing to ByteArrayOutputStream takes even longer(9s). I really don't understand it at all.

Comment: @Voooza: You might need to show us code that reproduces the problem.  Boil it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and edit it into the question.

Comment: Try changing the output format from png to jpeg. If that speeds up output then the png writer that your JDK is using is the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image encoding in java is pretty slow in general but you may also want to ensure you have the native libraries installed as they make quite a noticeable difference in performance.

http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html

Comment: I have followed that exact install guide(the Linux part) when installing JAI. Do I have native libraries? Should I install more? Thanks

Comment: If you followed that instruction they "should" be installed. When you boot up your app, watch you log files and look out for messages about being unable to find native libraries. If you don't see any the libraries should be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that ImageIO by default uses temporary files as cache when creating [ImageInputStreams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html) and [ImageOutputStreams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream.html). This can be switched off by calling [ImageIO.setUseCache(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#setUseCache-boolean-).

For a more detailed explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407944/5223047).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the

```
ImageIO
```

takes so long - maybe there is another problem, e.g.

- slow (network) connection to the client
- the generation (calculation) of the image takes a lot of time

Comment: Yes I am sure. I tried it with static image saved on disk. If I just read from FileInputStream and send to ServletOutputStream it's OK. On the same server and client I am able to get under 200 ms. But when I load It to BufferedImage and ImageIO.write() it out it takes 6s. I am logging timestamps after each function call and it really is in ImageIO. Checked several times by me and 2 of my colleagues