# Byte array to some sort of Java/Scala image. Performance considerations

Tags: java, image, scala

I am writing an FTP server that receives images and then resizes and uploads them.

My current process (pseudocode) is as follows:

```
val imagesAsBytes: Array[Byte] = ...
val bufferedImage: BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
uploadImage(bufferedImage)
```

That's the gist of it. I've left out the resizing because it's not important. Essentially, I serialise the `Array[Byte]` into a `BufferedImage` using the `ImageIO` module, and then resize it.

I have done some profiling, and I've noticed that creating a `BufferedImage` using `ImageIO` is horribly slow.

If I just upload the `Array[Byte]`, I can achieve about 4x the throughput, than if I actually try and convert it to a `BufferedImage`. The reason I can't just upload the `Array[Byte]`, is that I do need to resize the image. I am not tied to `BufferedImage`, it's just my first attempt.

Does anyone know of some ideas I can use to speed this up? Is there a better format I should be using over `BufferedImage`?

I've already considered pushing resizing out to a separate microservice and perform it asynchronously, but it's not an option for the first release.

Edit: I have reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132911/byte-array-to-buffered-image-conversion-slow) question, and am aware of this: `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: I don't think that decoding an image, resampling (resizing) it, and finally encoding again can be considered slow (4x) according to your numbers. Actually, it's surprisingly fast, compared to just copy the bytes... Or was that compared to decoding only? Anyway, what file format are you using? Some formats are heavier to en-/decode than others.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at more actively supported library (last release 4.0 at Feb 2020) like [scrimage](https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage). Under the hood it uses `java.awt.*`. At least in case of any issues you will be able to address them and get them resolved, moreover using more "scalish" API.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use external program from ImageMagic.