# Why ImageIO.read() SOOO slow?

Tags: java, inputstream, javax.imageio

So I'm trying to get a PNG image from stream.

```
image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

And this code is running for ten seconds! I thought the problem was in slow InputStream, so I tried to load it in buffer first.

```
byte[] bytes = inputStreamToBytes(inputStream);
image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

And guess what! It takes about 100ms to load it from InputStream to buffer, but hell of a lot of time just to read it from byte array! A ten (TEN) seconds to read! From a RAM!

I'm doing it on Raspberry PI. And yes, I understand it's a toy, not a real computer. So I tried to do it on my MacBook Air. Really, two seconds are better then ten. But still a lot for some 800x600 PNG. So why it so? And what to do?

Comment: Java's ImageIO is just flat out slow for everyone... I doubt you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: ^ That is a bold statement. However, can you provide (upload) the file that you are trying to load? It seems to be somewhat specific, but to verify this: Is it so slow for every arbitrary, random, 800x600 image, or only for this particular one? (Maybe it has some odd, unusual format, compression type or so...)

Comment: @Marco13 ImageIO does have a reputation for being inexplicably slow, even after examining the source code.

Comment: It's a screenshot from "adb shell screencap -p"

Comment: You are doing it wrong. ;-) ImageIO is using a disk cache by default, even if reading from an in-memory input stream... Try using [`ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#setUseCache(boolean)) to get a "free" speed improvement.

Comment: ImageIO.setUseCache(false) didn't help :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132911/byte-array-to-buffered-image-conversion-slow

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install Java Native IO libraries they are not installed by default.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/install-jai-imageio-1-0-01-139659.html

If you don't have this lib installed all operations on images are performed in java not natively.

Comment: While JAI (with native codecs, like libpng in this case) may help in some cases, I doubt JAI comes with prebuilt native binaries for Raspberry Pi. JAI hasn't been developed for several years. Creating your own JNI interface for libpng is likely a better option.

Comment: Does OpenJDK contain native IO?

Comment: @user1748526 JPEG encoding/decoding uses native code (libJPEG). Not native for anything else. AFAIK.