# Why does ToolkitImage getBufferedImage() return a null?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage

**I want to convert an `Image` to a `BufferedImage`. I know the following:**

```
Image tmp;
... //read, scale
BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(SMALL_SIZE, SMALL_SIZE,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
```

But it's really slow. I need `BufferedImage`, because I have to get pixel color data.
I found a possible way to do it, without drawing:

```
ToolkitImage ti = (ToolkitImage) tmp;
BufferedImage buffered = tmp.getBufferedImage();
```

**But it always returns `null`**. Can anyone offer a solution for this?

**EDIT:**
The bigger task (source of this problem) is here:
[Scale a BufferedImage the fastest and easiest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497853/scale-a-bufferdimage-the-fastest-and-easiest-way)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, noting that J2SE has no `ToolkitImage`, are you using Android?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I edited the question, is it better now? The ToolkitImage is in the sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.

Comment: Don't use classes in the `sun` hierarchy of packages!  They may not be in the next Oracle JRE, and probably would not be in the JRE of another manufacturer.

Comment: It would be great to not use this class at all, but I need a solution to convert the Image to BufferedImage as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same conversion issue with ToolkitImage to BufferedImage.

```
Graphics2D g2d = buffImage.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

-- was drawing nothing to the buffered image, and `image.getBufferedImage();` was `null`

That is what have helped, using the `ImageIcon` to init some internall stuff in the original `Image`.

```
ToolkitImage toolkitImage = (ToolkitImage) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("image.jpg");

Image temporary = new ImageIcon(toolkitImage).getImage();

BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage(toolkitImage.getWidth(), toolkitImage.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g2d = buffImage.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(temporary, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

After that buffImage contained the image from toolkitImage.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. For some weird reasons, I managed to get the image via the ImageIcon. So I loaded the byteArray(imageDate) into the ImageIcon and then read the image off the ImageIcon and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you query the `getHeight()` or `getWidth()` methods on the `ToolkitImage` you will trigger the generation of the internal `BufferedImage`. So your code would become:

```
ToolkitImage ti = (ToolkitImage) tmp;
ti.getWidth();
BufferedImage buffered = ti.getBufferedImage();
```

I doubt this will be any faster than the `drawImage()` method you described, but is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a faster way to convert `Image` to `BufferedImage` using only JDK.  If you are unrestricted, maybe you could write a faster solution in C or C++ and access via JNI.  I bet ImageMagick has some crazy fast, optimized routines.  **Edit**: This answer has a good suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7726679/257299

A different strategy would be to avoid calling `Image Toolkit.getImage(URL)`.  This requires a conversion to `BufferedImage`.  Instead, try: `BufferedImage ImageIO.read(File)`

About why `BufferedImage ToolkitImage.getBufferedImage()` always returns `null`:

1. `ToolkitImage` is part of the `sun` package which is not considered part of the JDK public API.  Avoid using directly.  I know: If you code Swing, you will see people breaking this rule often, since Sun made such heavy use of non-public classes in Swing.  (`SwingUtilities` does all kind of sneaky things with package-private methods and classes.)
2. Method `getBufferedImage()` returns a non-`null` reference if the buffered image has been **generated** internally by `TookitImage`.  Read that last sentence again.  The important term is *generated*.  This method is not "free" and surely incurs heavy processing cost to convert internal data to `BufferedImage`.  Most often (99%) the `BufferedImage` has not been generated, so the return value is `null`.  [JDK Source Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/image/ToolkitImage.java#ToolkitImage.getBufferedImage%28%29)