# How to get the Color of a specific pixel of an Image? - Java

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb, pixel

**Is it possible to get the Color of a specific pixel of an** `Image`**?**

I know how to get it from a `BufferedImage`:

```
Color color = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y));
```

*But that doesn't work with a* `java.awt.Image` *that looks for example like this:*

```
Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way of doing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [ImageIO.read returns a BufferedImage.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-)

Comment: @VGR But I can initialize an `Image` that way...

Comment: Yes, polymorphism allows you to *refer* to it as an Image, or an Object, or even as a Transparency instance. But regardless of whether your code treats it like an Image, it is actually a BufferedImage.

Comment: @VGR But shouldn't it work than?!

Comment: Change `Image` to `BufferedImage` or `((BufferedImage) image).getRGB(x, y)`

Comment: If your `image` variable is declared as `BufferedImage image`, it will.  If you declare it to be of type `Image`, it will still be a BufferedImage when the program *runs,* but the *compiler* doesn’t run the program.  The compiler only knows that you have a variable of type Image in your code, and the Image class does not have a [getRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) method.

Comment: @JaredRummler I know that I could Change the `Image` to a `BufferedImage`, But in my code it has to be an `Image`. And I tryed to cast it to a `BufferedImage`, but it didn't wort. I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage`

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIO.read(file)` should return a `BufferedImage`. You can also use `PixelGrabber` to get a specific color. Example:

```
private static Color getSpecificColor(Image image, int x, int y) {
  if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
    return new Color(((BufferedImage) image).getRGB(x, y));
  }
  int width = image.getWidth(null);
  int height = image.getHeight(null);
  int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
  PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
  try {
    grabber.grabPixels();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  int c = pixels[x * width + y];
  int  red = (c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
  int  green = (c & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
  int  blue = c & 0x000000ff;
  return new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

`ToolkitImage` also has a method to get the `BufferedImage` but may return null: [Why does ToolkitImage getBufferedImage() return a null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522965/why-does-toolkitimage-getbufferedimage-return-a-null)

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0257.html